# Independence of Events with Dice

Tags: probability, independence

Let's say rolling a high number (4, 5, or 6) is event A, rolling a very high number (5 or 6) is event B, and rolling an even number (2, 4, or 6) is event C.

The question is why are events B and C independent while events A and C are dependent? I understand this has to do with P(X and Y)=P(X)P(Y) for independence, but can someone please explain why these two are dependent and independent? Thanks.

Comment: Informally, it's because event $A$ is "rich with evens".  That is, knowing that $A$ occurred is evidence that you rolled an even number.  That is not the case for $B$...knowing that $B$ occurred isn't evidence for either even or odd.

Comment: "*I understand this has to do with P(X and Y)=P(X)P(Y)*"  That is all that needs to be said and understood.  Here $P(A\cap C) = P(\{4,6\})=\frac{2}{6}\neq \frac{3}{6}\times\frac{3}{6}=P(A)\times P(C)$ so they are not independent.  Meanwhile $P(B\cap C) = P(\{6\})=\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{2}=P(B)\times P(C)$ so $B$ and $C$ are independent.  The informal explanation is fine when it is quickly visible and apparent, however in some more challenging scenarios your intuition can and will fail you so it is always best to go via the basic definition.

Comment: @lulu That makes very good sense, thank you for this, helped me realize much easier.

Comment: @jmoravitz Thanks for the help. If $P(A and B)=P(A)P(B)$ for two arbitrary events $A,B$, does that mean $A$ and $B$ must be independent?

Comment: By definition, yes.